# Laravel - Long initialisation time

Tags: php, performance, laravel, initialization, long-integer

I maintain several Laravel projects. They usually boot quite quickly but I have that one project which boots very slow.

Project is written in Laravel 5.0, uses PHP 5.4.24, EasyPHP DevServer on Windows Server 2012.

Here's a screenshot from Chrome Clockwork plugin:
[image: Laravel initialisation time]

For example in another Laravel project(same version - 5.0) running on my local computer(not very fast) it takes 80 - 140 ms to initialise. Furthermore, `Application initialisation` event ends when `Router dispatch` starts which is clearly not the case in the picture above.

Another issue(maybe related, maybe not) is that whenever I run `composer update` it takes several minutes to run all those tasks with merely 6 requirements

Comment: For the composer issue you might have xdebug enabled in php.ini but it depends on the host.

Comment: Might be a too high memory_limit setting inside your php.ini! I had the same problem (3sec Laravel boot time), try to lower the setting

Comment: @Sliq, nah, it was just that I was running on windows. On Mac or Linux the issue no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the problem using logs [error ,warning] in your server .in most scenario you will see the problem in server log file.